# Required methods for a VB.NET service?

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I’m taking over a project in VB.NET. The project is a windows service that is responsible for processing certain information from several databases and creates a text files with information required by the business. I'm having problems when starting the service once compiled. Every time I try to start the service the following error appears.

> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the Start or Control
>   Request in a Timely Fashion.

My impression is that for some reason when I compile the project, the executable that is created does not have the characteristics that distinguish it as a Windows service. When I double click the .exe file no error appears anywhere. But through the Service Manager never works.

I saw in the code base that the `Public Sub Main ()` method is commented. My question is, it is a requirement that in order to compile the project to be recognized as a service a `Public Sub Main ()` method should be defined at least once in the code base?

Comment: Something does not sound right with your project, are you:  Inheriting from  System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase ? i would have a look at the windows service template and compare your code to it, File > New > Windows Service

Comment: Yes! 
```<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class <ServiceName>
    Inherits System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase```

Comment: I compare my code with the windows service template and basically is the same. The only difference is the server name.